# Fetch the current user's attributes - Cognito Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using below function to fetch user attributes. In iOS application when I'm running this function all data are coming each time in different order eg. [sub, synchronized, id, email] next time [id, sub, email, synchronized]. In android application all data are in the same order every time.

```
Future<void> fetchCurrentUserAttributes() async {
  try {
    final result = await Amplify.Auth.fetchUserAttributes();
      print('sub: ${result[0]}');
      print('synchronized: ${result[1]}');
      print('id: ${result[2]}');
      print('email: ${result[3]}');
  } on AuthException catch (e) {
    print(e.message);
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why? I want to store these attributes in array to use it in other functions in the application, so I need all data in the same order every time I invoke this function.

Comment: Why dont you just use a model class that will store your complete future value. Later, you can just call the model class to extract values (like sub, id, etc). In that way, it won't matter in which order the data is coming.

Comment: Do you get execution order guarantees for un-awaited statements in an async function? In any case, if you need a sorted array, sort it. Don't count on undocumented behavior in cognito.

Comment: The more important part is how you store the values in results. As if they are not stored correctly, you will never get them in order. So post the code which keeps values in the "result" array.

Answer (score 0):

`await Amplify.Auth.fetchUserAttributes()` returns `List<AuthUserAttribute>`.
You can convert List to Map and used it by its key.

```
  Future<Map<String, String>> getUserAttributes() async {
    final attributes = await Amplify.Auth.fetchUserAttributes();
    final data = {for (var e in attributes) e.userAttributeKey.key: e.value};
    return data;
  }
```